# Need help with Xpath methods in javascript (selectSingleNode, selectNodes)

Tags: javascript, xpath

I want to optimize my javascript but I ran into a bit of trouble. I'm using XSLT transformation and the basic idea is to get a part of the XML and subquery it so the calls are faster and less expensive. This is a part of the XML:

```
<suite>
<table id="spis" runat="client">
    <rows>                      
        <row id="spis_1">               
        <dispatch>'2008', '288627'</dispatch>       
        <data col="urGod">
            <title>2008</title>
            <description>Ur. god.</description>
        </data>
        <data col="rbr">
             <title>288627</title>
             <description>Rbr.</description>
        </data>

...

    </rows>
</table>
</suite>
```

In the page, this is the javascript that works with this:

```
// this is my global variable for getting the elements so I just get the most
// I can in one call    

elemCollection = iDom3.Table.all["spis"].XML.DOM.selectNodes("/suite/table/rows/row").context;

//then I have the method that uses this by getting the subresults from elemCollection
//rest of the method isn't interesting, only the selectNodes call

_buildResults = function (){
        var _RowList = elemCollection.selectNodes("/data[@col = 'urGod']/title");
        var tmpResult = [''];
        var substringResult="";
        for (i=0; i<_RowList.length; i++) {
            tmpResult.push(_RowList[i].text,iDom3.Global.Delimiter);
        }
...


//this variant works

elemCollection = iDom3.Table.all["spis"].XML.DOM

_buildResults = function (){
        var _RowList = elemCollection.selectNodes("/suite/table/rows/row/data[@col = 'urGod']/title");
        var tmpResult = [''];
        var substringResult="";
        for (i=0; i<_RowList.length; i++) {
            tmpResult.push(_RowList[i].text,iDom3.Global.Delimiter);
        }

...
```

The problem is, I can't find a way to use the subresults to get what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to select nodes from a collection ([NodeList](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/xmldom/quickref/obj_nodeList.html#item)).

```
elemCollection.selectNodes("/data[@col = 'urGod']/title");
```

Try to select a node from a single item ([Node](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/xml_dom/16026.asp)) from the collection such as:

```
elemCollection[i].selectSingleNode("/data[@col = 'urGod']/title")
```

Added to your code (without data validation and assuming we want the first match for the col attribute):

```
_buildResults = function (){
        var tmpResult = [''];
        var substringResult="";
        for (i=0; i<elemCollection.length; i++) {
            tmpResult.push(elemCollection[i].selectSingleNode("/data[@col = 'urGod']/title").text,iDom3.Global.Delimiter);
        }
```

Comment: Performance gain is significant, JSLItmus results for similar functions, first uses elemCollection = iDom3.Table.all["spis"].XML.DOM
                     second 

elemCollection = iDom3.Table.all["spis"].XML.DOM.selectNodes("/suite/table/rows/row")


and then 

elemCollection[i].selectSingleNode("./data[@col = 'urGod']/title")

http://tinyurl.com/32x58pd


Btw, I've had "context" at the end of elemCollection, that also needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to iterate the elemCollection list, and then do this query:

```
./data[@col = 'urGod']/title
```